# Formatting a callback function in d3.js to place symbols on a multiseries linechart

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, svg, d3.js, associative-array

I am attempting to place symbols on a multiseries line chart. In the [d3.js API reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-symbol), symbols are positioned using a transform function:

```
vis.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol());
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to apply this to build my own function(d) callback function to access d.date and several d.temperature sets as shown below and described in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955):

```
var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
        name: name,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, temperature: +d[name]}; <-- stored in 'd.values'
    })
};});
```

the best I can come up with through trial and error is the following, which I am providing for comic relief:

```
for (i=0; i<cities[0].values.length; i++) // note: for comic relief only
{
    vis.selectAll(".class")
    .data(cities)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.values[i].date) + "," + y(d.values[i].temperature) + ")"; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol())
}
```

It actually works, which I think is hilarious, but my attempts to write a properly nested function have so far failed. For instance, this gives transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.values, function(c) { return c.date}) + "," + y(d.values, function(c) { return c.temperature}) + ")"; })
```

What am I not understanding? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attempt code you are binding `data` but I think you mean `cities`, right?  The `data` variable in the example you link to contains the data as it is read from the TSV file so it doesn't have a `values` property.

The `cities` variable points to a nested data structure where each city (the series) contains a list of  data points that comprise the line (the values).  This nesting is convenient when creating the paths because each city is a separate path and the path definition is made of up of the list of values.  But for applying shapes, you no longer have any use for the grouping.  You just need a list of values so you can create/position a shape per value.

Instead of trying to extract the values out of the nested structure, it would probably be easiest to perform a data transformation to produce a flat list of values. Note that I put the city name into each node because you will probably want to use this to apply a per-city color or type to your shapes:

```
var values = [];
cities.forEach(function(city) {
    city.values.forEach(function(v) {
        values.push({
            date: v.date,
            temperature: v.temperature,
            city: city.name
        });
    });
});
```

Then you can simply use this array to create the shapes.  Each value contains all the information you need to put it into the right place.  To copy some code from your question:

```
vis.selectAll("path")
    .data(values)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.temperature) + ")"; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol());
```

This will create all the same shapes but as mentioned above you can use d.city to change the symbol type or stroke color.  You can use a simple ordinal scale or color scale with city names as domain to do this.

** EDIT:
As per your comment expressing a desire to do this using the grouped data structure without further transformation, here is a way to do that with multiple data joins in a loop:

```
for (i=0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    vis.selectAll(".class")
        .data(cities[i].values)
        .enter().append("path")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.temperature) + ")"; })
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol())
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to reflect that I'm using cities. I tested your flat list and it works as intended, however for a large number of cities there seems to be an upper limit? -- I can't seem to display anymore than ~500 symbols, even though all the data properly exists within the flat list of values. hmm... I'm going to continue to experiment with accessing the nested structure directly, as I'm very curious how to do it. I'll mark this as correct in a few days if I can't get the direct method to work.

Comment: I've added a bit to the answer to show an alternative approach that modifies your loop slightly to create the symbols without the data transformation I proposed originally.

Comment: This is great, the upper limit bug was indeed my own, and the two methods you suggest work well. Together they demonstrate very well how to access and set up my arrays, which is what I was hoping for.